# Append int to end of string or textbox name in a For Loop C#

Tags: c#, string, for-loop

I have a C# application in which there are several textboxes with the same name except for a number on the end which starts at 1 and goes to 19.  I was hoping to use a for loop to dynamically add values to these text boxes by using an arraylist.  There will be situations where there will not be 19 items in the arrayList so some text boxes will be unfilled.  Here is my sample code for what I am trying to do.  Is this possible to do?

```
  for (int count = 0; count < dogList.Count; count++)
        {
            regUKCNumTextBox[count+1].Text=(dogList[count].Attributes["id"].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried your sample code? If it doesn't work, what errors are you seeing, or what unexpected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you've got a collection of text boxes that are to be filled out top-to-bottom?  Then yes, a collection of `TextBox` seems appropriate.

If you stick your `TextBox` references in an array or a `List<TextBox>` -- I wouldn't use an `ArrayList` as it's considered deprecated in favor of `List<T>` -- then yes, you can do that:

```
TextBox[] regUKCNumTextBox = new [] 
    {
         yourTextBoxA,
         yourTextBoxB,
         ...
    };
```

Then yes your logic is possible, you can also query the control by it's name, though that would be heavier at runtime - so it's a tradeoff.  Yes, in this solution you must set up a collection to hold your text box references, but it will be more performant.

Comment: when I tried to do this I got an error. I tried to do this:                                                                                                                                     TextBox[] regUKCNumTextBox = new []
            {
                regUKCNumTextBox1;
                regUKCNumTextBox2;
                regUKCNumTextBox3;
                regUKCNumTextBox4;
                regUKCNumTextBox5;
                regUKCNumTextBox6;
                regUKCNumTextBox7;
                regUKCNumTextBox8;
                regUKCNumTextBox9;
                            }

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

(By the way I am assuming you use WinForms)

```
for (int count = 0; count < dogList.Count; count++)
{
   object foundTextBox = this.Controls.Find("nameofTextBoxes" + [count+1]);

   if (foundTextBox != null)
   {
      if (foundTextBox is TextBox)
      {
         ((TextBox)foundTextBox).Text=(dogList[count].Attributes["id"].Value.ToString());
      }
   }

}
```

With this code you are trying to find a `Control` form your `Form`s `Controls` collection. Then you have to make sure the control is of the `TextBox` type. When it is; cast it to a `TextBox` and do what you want with it. In this case; assign a value to the `Text` property.

It would be more efficient to keep a collection of your `TextBox`es like in the solution offered by James Michael Hare

Comment: It works except the value in the text box is System.Xml.XmlElement

Comment: Try `.InnerText` instead of `.Value.ToString()`

Comment: Still produces the same result.  It is odd because if I have the exact same code except just assign it to the textbox directly using its name it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes; something doesn't seem quite right with the overall design there; but looking past that, here's a quick stab at some pseudo code that might work:

```
for (int count = 0; count < dogList.Count; count++)
{
    var stringName = string.Format("myTextBoxName{0}", count);
    var ctrl = FindControl(stringName);
    if(ctrl == null) continue;
    ctrl.Text = dogList[count];
}
```